# Print console log with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Would you like to learn how to print this CONSOLE.LOG message in a html.

```
this.obj = function () {
        return console.log("Teste");

    }
```

Comment: Are you calling obj somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Please inject the [$log service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log) in function and then use it:

```
this.obj = function () 
   $log.info("Teste");
}
```

Comment: What does this actually give you over console.log?  I've always done it this way but I have to admit I don't really know what the advantage is.

Comment: How is the call in html?

Comment: Simple service for logging. Default implementation safely writes the message into the browser's console (if present).

The main purpose of this service is to simplify debugging and troubleshooting.

Comment: @YehudiMikhael you don't call it in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myObj()
{

this.obj = function()
{
console.log('hello');
}
}

var myobj = new myObj();
myobj.obj();
```

Comment: How is the call in html?

Comment: @YehudiMikhael : You are using 'this' so I suppose you must be defining function inside an object therefore I have edited my answer according to that.